# Problems finding median of arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I keep getting `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Double>` The arrayList is pulling numbers from my Test class. I made the if to determine if the arrayList has an even amount of values in it or an odd, for I could use the two different ways to determine the median. But I'm not able to get the median formula to work.

```
public class Data {

private ArrayList<Double> sets;

public Data(double[] set) {
    this.sets = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (double i : set) {
        this.sets.add(i);
    }
}

public double getMedian(){
    Collections.sort(sets);

    double middle = sets.size()/2;
        if (sets.size()%2 == 1) {
           middle = (sets[sets.size()/2] + sets[sets.size()/2 - 1])/2;
        } else {
            middle = sets[sets.size() / 2];
        }
      return middle;
}
```

Comment: `sets` is an `ArrayList` not an array, you can't use the index notation like `sets[index]`, which is for regular arrays . Use `sets.get(index)` instead.

Comment: Short answer, an ArrayList is not an Array. It is an Object using an Array so you need to use methods to set/get values in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is on the line where you find the middle:

```
middle = (sets[sets.size()/2] + sets[sets.size()/2 - 1])/2;
```

You can use [index] notation only with arrays. You need to use getter/setter methods to access the elements of an ArrayList. This should work:

```
middle = (sets.get(sets.size()/2) + sets.get(sets.size()/2 - 1))/2;
```

Comment: Since this line was underline (with an IDE) or nice shown with `javac` to OP. You should explain why there is a need to use `.get(index)` in an `ArrayList`. There is not really an explanation to his problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, if you have an array with 4 elements [0..3], to find the median you just do 4/2 - 1 = 1 and index 1 is the median of array. Now if array is 5, you just do 5/2 = 2 and 2 is the median.

```
public double getMedian() {
    Collections.sort(sets);
    int middle = sets.size() / 2;
    middle = middle > 0 && middle % 2 == 0 ? middle - 1 : middle;
    return sets.get(middle);
}
```

Comment: because if you have an array with 4 elements [0..3], to find the median you just do 4/2 - 1 = 1 and index 1 is the median of array. Now if array is 5, you just do 5/2 = 2 and 2 is the median. I can change middle-- to meddle - 1 for more reading

Answer (score 1):

You are using `arrayList` not an array, so ArrayList's `get(int index)` method must be used to access data. This is used like this :

```
middle = (sets.get(sets.size()/2) +sets.get((sets.size()/2)-1) )/2;
```

Comment: Could you try to reformulate your sentence, this doesn't means much ;) an please, explain why it can't be use like an Array.

Comment: Sure , tnx for remidinding

Answer (score -1):

Make sure in your if statement you check if it's equal to 0.

```
public double getMedian(){
    Collections.sort(sets);

    double middle = sets.size()/2;
        if (sets.size()%2 == 0) {
           middle = (sets.get(sets.size()/2) + sets.get(sets.size()/2 - 1))/2;
        } else {
            middle = sets[sets.size() / 2];
        }
      return middle;
}
```