# Get the median of arraylist of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking to get the median an arraylist of arraylist of doubles and I require help?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double> > List = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double> >();
```

If you look at the list of list as the following example:

```
c1-5.0,4.5,10.3,3.5

c2-2.5,1.0,7.8,8.6

c3-6.0,5.6,9.6,9.5
```

It should go to this

```
c1-5.0,4.5,9.6,8.6
```

Line that I tried but shows an error

```
middle =Double.sum(List.get((List.size()/2)), List.get(List.size()/2 - 1));
```

Comment: Hi There. You would have to better elaborate your question. What is `media`, I am assuming `median` but you are not actually calculating median as per your expected output. Also post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't see how that line of code has anything to do with the task at hand. Your nested lists are all 4 long, so you'll need to calculate 4 different median. For that you'd need a loop, but I see no loop. For the median at index `i`, you need to get and sort the values at index `i` of each nested list. I see no see sorting logic. If the number of nested lists is odd, you take the middle of the sorted values, but I see no code doing any such logic. Shall I go on? Please make a better attempt.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41117975/1425697

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
List<List<Double> > doublesLists = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList(5.0,4.5,10.3,3.5),
        Arrays.asList(2.5,1.0,7.8,8.6),
        Arrays.asList(6.0,5.6,9.6,9.5)
);
```

You can do:

```
List<Double> medians = IntStream.range(0, doublesLists.get(0).size())
        .mapToDouble(i -> {
            List<Double> doubles = doublesLists.stream()
                    .mapToDouble(doublesList -> doublesList.get(i))
                    .sorted()
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return doubles.size()%2 == 1 ? doubles.get(doubles.size()/2) : (doubles.get(doubles.size()/2) + doubles.get(doubles.size()/2-1))/2;
        })
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(medians);
```

Output:

```
[5.0, 4.5, 9.6, 8.6]
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the list of medians per column, the input list should be transposed (columns converted into rows), then sorted, and only after that a median value should be calculated after checking the length of the column for [being odd or even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median).

Also, extra checks may be needed to discard null/empty sublists in the input data.

It may be convenient to use Stream API to implement this task like this:

```java
static List<Double> medians(List<List<Double>> data) {
    int maxCols = data.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(List::size).max().orElse(0);
    return IntStream.range(0, maxCols)
        .mapToObj(j -> IntStream
            .range(0, data.size())
            .filter(i -> data.get(i) != null && j < data.get(i).size())
            .mapToObj(i -> data.get(i).get(j))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),
                list -> list.size() % 2 == 1 
                    ? list.get(list.size() / 2) 
                    : (list.get(list.size() / 2) + list.get(list.size() / 2 - 1)) /2
                ))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(medians(
    Arrays.asList(
        List.of(5.0, 4.5, 10.3, 3.5),
        List.of(2.5, 1.0,  7.8),
        List.of(6.0, 5.6,  9.6, 9.5, 12.0),
        null,
        Collections.emptyList()
    )
));
```

Output

```
[5.0, 4.5, 9.6, 6.5, 12.0]
```